# How can I debug why the background image is not displaying?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, background

I have some code [that works with Angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibtx1.jpg), that [does not work with Vue.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRO6E.jpg).

```
bodyElement.style.setProperty('background-image', 'url(./assets/pictures/pexels-chevanon-photography-1108099.jpg)');             
bodyElement.style.setProperty('background-size', 'cover');
```

Here is the [Angular file tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d00Jm.png) and the [Vue.js file tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3bVu.jpg).

How can I debug the issue?

---

Background issue solved: I placed the background picture in the "public" folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the element background image you can use the codes below:

```
bodyElement.style.backgroundImage='url(./assets/pictures/pexels-chevanon-photography-1108099.jpg)';
bodyElement.style.backgroundSize='cover';
```